# UseExceptionHandling failing after stream.CopyToAsync() call

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, exception, asp.net-core-webapi, middleware

I am having an issue with UseExceptionHandler in .Net Core 3.1 WebApi starts failing to trigger after copying the response body to a stream. I am using a middleware to intercept incoming requests and outgoing responses for a webapi project and logs records to a table. It works fine until the stream.CopyToAsync() method is called. Any exceptions after that does not trigger the ExceptionHandler, even though a local try/catch will still catch an exception and rethrowing the exception in the catch block still doesn't cause the ExceptionHandler to trigger.

Invoke Method

```
 public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {   
               Stream originalBody = context.Response.Body;
                try
                {
                
                    using var memStream = new MemoryStream();
                    context.Response.Body = memStream;
                    await _next(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    await LogResponse(context, originalBody, memStream).ConfigureAwait(false);


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex; 
                }
                finally
                {
                    context.Response.Body = originalBody;
                    originalBody.Close();                    
                }
            }
        }
```

LogResponse Method

```
 private async Task LogResponse(HttpContext context, Stream originalBody, MemoryStream stream)
    {
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        string body = await new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        
        //This is the line of code that breaks UseExceptionHandling pipeline
        await stream.CopyToAsync(originalBody).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var resp = new ApiLogItemRequest()
        {
            AppName = "AppName",
            CreatedBy = "AppName",
            DateTime = DateTime.Now,                
            RawBodyJson = body,
            TraceIdentifier = context.TraceIdentifier
        };

        await _logHelper.LogRawHttpBodyItem(resp);
    }
```

Any thoughts or hints would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out the issue. The `originalBody` variable was null, then an exception was being thrown by the `ExceptionHandler` creating a weird error loop in the middleware, causing it to fail to execute the handler's code. I'm assuming it has something to do with the context being written with a null response from the `CopyToAsync()` line of code, but I'm not 100% certain on the why.

I changed the code so that it insured only copying when `originalBody` is not null and it fixed the issue.

I recognized the `ExceptionHandler` hang up in the debug console. `ExceptionMiddleware`'s `Invoke` only should have been called once and done, but it was followed by `HandleException` then `Invoke` again which leads me to think there was some exception in the `ExceptionHandler` causing it to skip out the code there.

(I didn't state originally, but the root issue was that the `originalBody = context.Response.Body` was being written **before** `_next(context);` In this case, there is no response body to copy. That logic should have occurred after `_next(context)`

```
System.Exception: Test exception
   at Project.Api.Middleware.ApiRequestResponseLog.Invoke(HttpContext context) in C:\GIT\Project\Project.Api\Middleware\ApiRequestResponseLog.cs:line 82
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
//These below shouldn't have occured
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.HandleException(HttpContext context, ExceptionDispatchInfo edi)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()
```